# creating table from json data

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON data which I want to create a table from it but I am getting this error from the console: `TypeError: obj.labels[i].getAttribute is not a function`.
creating the table header is okay, I only get the error when I try to populate the table with data.

I want the car table to have the header `[id, carname, year, registration]`

The error is coming from this line: `span.innerText = obj.labels[i].getAttribute(attrs[j]);`

I don't know why I am getting the error, I need some help extracting the car data and populate the table.

```js
var attrs = ["id", "name", "year", "registration"];
var jsonString =
  '{\n' +
  '    "labels": [\n' +
  '        {\n' +
  '            "name": "test",\n' +
  '            "age": 33,\n' +
  '            "contact": test,\n' +
  '            "cars": [\n' +
  '                {"id": 2222, "carname": "ford", "year": 2000, "registration": cd60}\n' +
  '                {"id": 3333, "carname": "BMW", "year": 2012, "registration": fs41}\n' +
  '            ]\n' +
  '        }\n' +
  '    ]\n' +
  '}\n' +
  '';



var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);


//create table
var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("mytable")
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
table.appendChild(tableBody);


//header
for (var i = 0; i < obj.labels.length; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var j = 0; j < attrs.length; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('th');
    td.width = '75';
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = attrs[j];
    td.appendChild(span);
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);
}

//body
for (var i = 0; i < obj.labels.length; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var j = 0; j < attrs.length; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.width = '75';
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = obj.labels[i].getAttribute(attrs[j]);
    td.appendChild(span);
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);
}


myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I need some help extracting the car data and populate the table.

Comment: Do access attribute values this way: labels[i][attrs[j]

Comment: You need to ask a **question**.  Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to display car details in a HTML table. Your input JSON data structure is as follows:

- `labels` has a set of objects (let's say each of these is `label`)
- each label has properties and a set of `cars`
- each `car` has properties

To access car details your code will like:

```
var attrs = ["id", "carname", "year", "registration"];
var jsonString =
    '{\n' +
    '    "labels": [\n' +
    '        {\n' +
    '            "name": "test",\n' +
    '            "age": 33,\n' +
    '            "contact": "test",\n' +
    '            "cars": [\n' +
    '                {"id": 2222, "carname": "ford", "year": 2000, "registration": "cd60"},\n' +
    '                {"id": 3333, "carname": "BMW", "year": 2012, "registration": "fs41"}\n' +
    '            ]\n' +
    '        }\n' +
    '    ]\n' +
    '}\n' +
    '';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.log(obj)
for (var i = 0; i < obj.labels.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < obj.labels[i]['cars'].length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < attrs.length; k++) {
            console.log(obj.labels[0]['cars'][j][attrs[k]])
        }
        console.log("=========")
    }
}
```

**Edit**

The above iteration may look like very basic. Here are the short forms of the above for loop:

If you want to refer to `attrs` to read car attributes:

```
[...obj.labels].forEach(element => {
    element['cars'].forEach(car => {
        for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
            console.log(car[attrs[i]]);
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to read all car attributes:

```
[...obj.labels].forEach(element => {
    element['cars'].forEach(car => Object.keys(car).map(attr => 
        console.log(attr + " " + car[attr])));
});
```